# accidentally comitted folder with plots - how to exclude this folder from future comits?

Tags: git, directory

I accidentally committed a folder containing plots. The shell is slowed down through this mistake and I want to exclude that folder for future commits without loosing the changes made in the code-file (R).
Any Ideas how to do this?

Comment: Did you push your commit. Is there any commit after the one that added the plots?

Comment: no commit afterwards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your plot folder name is `plots`. You can remove the plots from git

```sh
git rm --cached -r plots
```

Then add your plots folder to the `.gitignore` if you don't want to commit it again by mistake

```sh
echo plots/ >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
```

Then you can `amend` your commit (edit the commit).

```sh
# --no-edit prevents git from asking you to prompt the commit title again
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Comment: but what if there are 300 plots in this folder? How can I do what you described withoout doing it for every plot?

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick answers and I'll try what you recommended! have a nice weekend!

Comment: I didn't get an error message, so I think, it worked. And if I now later want to commit new changes in the code, I don't have to do anything else but  "git add . " and "git commit ", or is there something to do with .gitignore and this directory again?

Comment: @michel The .gitignore file will be added to your repository, so it will exclude plots as long as they are in the plots directory, and as long as you don't change the .gitignore content. You can add other files to exclude (IDE specific files, datasets, etc). Doc : https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please note that your next questions should include more details, to help people answer you. You could have specified your directory structure in your question. Also, don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem.